# facing issues in putting scrollview in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

How to include scrollview in my below xml file..where ever i place the scrollview the display gets messed up..
so before including scrollview this is my xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/prop"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/txte1"
        android:textSize = "20dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:textColor = "#757575"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vault"
        android:textColor = "#757575"
        android:textSize = "15dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:id="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />


   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:id="@+id/txte3"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:layout_above="@+id/textView21"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView19"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView19" />

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Email"
       android:textColor = "#757575"
       android:textSize = "15dp"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


  <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Pob"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView22" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Pin"
       android:textColor = "#757575"
       android:textSize = "15dp"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte6"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView23" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dob"
        android:id="@+id/txte7"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txte6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Doc"
        android:id="@+id/txte8"
         />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vault Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-mail"
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte4" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Place of Birth"
       android:id="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Postal-pin"
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte6"

        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte6" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Date of Birth"
         android:id="@+id/textView25"
         android:layout_below="@+id/txte7"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte7"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Education"
        android:id="@+id/textView200"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.miisky.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is how it will look.[image]

please can anyone suggest where to include scrollview for the above xml.

**EDIT**
if i place scrollview like below..texts are overlapping..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >


<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/prop"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/txte1"
        android:textSize = "20dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:textColor = "#757575"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vault"
        android:textColor = "#757575"
        android:textSize = "15dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:id="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />


   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:id="@+id/txte3"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:layout_above="@+id/textView21"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView19"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView19" />

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Email"
       android:textColor = "#757575"
       android:textSize = "15dp"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


  <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Pob"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView22" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Pin"
       android:textColor = "#757575"
       android:textSize = "15dp"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
       android:id="@+id/txte6"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView23" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dob"
        android:id="@+id/txte7"
       android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txte6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Doc"
        android:id="@+id/txte8"
         />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vault Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-mail"
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte4" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Place of Birth"
       android:id="@+id/textView23"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte5"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Postal-pin"
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte6"

        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte6" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Date of Birth"
         android:id="@+id/textView25"
         android:layout_below="@+id/txte7"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte7"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Education"
        android:id="@+id/textView200"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.miisky.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is the display[image]

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have kept image and texts(name and hello) static and applied scrollview like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/prop"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView10" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/txte1"
                android:textSize = "20dp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:textColor = "#757575"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txte1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/layout1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vault"
                android:textColor = "#757575"
                android:textSize = "15dp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:id="@+id/txte2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/container_body"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile"
                android:id="@+id/txte3"
                android:textStyle = "bold"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor = "#757575"
                android:textSize = "15dp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:id="@+id/txte4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pob"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txte5"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView22" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pin"
                android:textColor = "#757575"
                android:textSize = "15dp"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:id="@+id/txte6"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView23" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dob"
                android:id="@+id/txte7"
                android:textStyle = "bold"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txte6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView21" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vault Number"
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txte2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile Number"
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-mail"
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txte4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Place of Birth"
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txte5"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Postal-pin"
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txte6"

                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte6"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Birth"
                android:id="@+id/textView25"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txte7"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txte7"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txte7" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Education"
                android:id="@+id/textView200"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Education1"
                android:id="@+id/textView00"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView200"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView200"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView200"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Education1"
                android:id="@+id/textView010"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView00"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView00"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView00"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Doc"
                android:id="@+id/txte8"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txte1"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txte1" />
        </RelativeLayout>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.miisky.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all elements inside the scrollview?

Comment: Have you tried to change the arrangement in the layout view after you added the scrollview?

Comment: Sorry. Try to change the arrangement of the elements in "design",after you have put all in the scroll view.

Comment: i have already tried everything..dint got the result..so ended up in posting this here..

Comment: Have you also tried to use ScrollView insted of RelativeLayout? Or put ScrollView inside it.

Answer (score 0):

> Just add `android:fillViewport="true"` in it.

**Refer this.**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: it will display upto textview25..and it is not scrolling also..textView200 is not displaying..

Comment: It will able to scroll when you have more or big data inside your screen.

Comment: i have already added 2-3 more textviews...but it will display like the 1st image i have uploaded here..below that nothing is displaying/scrolling..